# What font size should I use for navigational breadcrumbs?

Tags: readability, breadcrumbs

I would like to know what font size I should use for the navigation breadcrumbs on my website.

Assuming that `16px` is my default font size, should I am for `11px` for the breadcrumbs? Or would that be too low?

Answer (score 1):

There are not principles about breadcrumb dimensions, usually is the same of paragraph text. A good rule is to set breadcrumb dimension less than the primary navigation.

**To know more:**
[12 Effective Guidelines For Breadcrumb Usability and SEO](http://usabilitygeek.com/12-effective-guidelines-for-breadcrumb-usability-and-seo/)

Comment: i understand... However about your guide linked, i'm surprised for "10", where suggest not use text lime "You are here". For example "steve krug" suggest to use it... What do you think about?

Comment: @user3162975 It means to avoid unnecessary text like "you are here", because breadcrumb should be recognized clearly as the navigation path, without superfluous indications.

Comment: But I believe that a novice user does not recognize the breadcrumbs, then the text "unnecessary" could be uile (losuggerisce also Steve Krug in his famous book "don't make me think") ... anyway back to the main question, do you think that a font-size of 12px (with the body to 14px) will be fine?